# Exploit failed: NoMethodError undefined method `smtp_send_recv' for #<Module:exploit/unix/smtp/exim4_string_format

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I was trying to run an exploit using Metasploit's Exim tool. In the process I will have used the `exim4_string_format` module. I gave as information a `RHOST, LHOSTS AND LPORT`. To attack the `reverse_perl` payload. As a consequence this error happened:

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.56.2:443 
[*] 192.168.56.5:25 - Connecting to 192.168.56.5:25 ...
[*] 192.168.56.5:25 - Server: 220 localhost ESMTP Exim 4.68 Thu, 22 Dec 2022 23:01:22 +0000
[-] 192.168.56.5:25 - Exploit failed: NoMethodError undefined method `smtp_send_recv' for #<Module:exploit/unix/smtp/exim4_string_format datastore=[{"WORKSPACE"=>nil, "VERBOSE"=>false, "WfsDelay"=>2, "EnableContextEncoding"=>false, "ContextInformationFile"=>nil, "DisablePayloadHandler"=>false, "RHOSTS"=>"192.168.56.5", "RPORT"=>25, "SSL"=>false, "SSLServerNameIndication"=>nil, "SSLVersion"=>"Auto", "SSLVerifyMode"=>"PEER", "SSLCipher"=>nil, "Proxies"=>nil, "CPORT"=>nil, "CHOST"=>nil, "ConnectTimeout"=>10, "TCP::max_send_size"=>0, "TCP::send_delay"=>0, "MAILFROM"=>"root@localhost", "MAILTO"=>"postmaster@localhost", "EHLO_NAME"=>nil, "SourceAddress"=>nil, "SkipEscalation"=>false, "SkipVersionCheck"=>false, "PAYLOAD"=>"cmd/unix/reverse_perl", "LHOST"=>"192.168.56.2", "LPORT"=>443, "UNPARSED_RHOSTS"=>"192.168.56.5", "RHOSTNAME"=>nil, "ReverseListenerBindPort"=>nil, "ReverseAllowProxy"=>false, "ReverseListenerComm"=>nil, "ReverseListenerBindAddress"=>nil, "ReverseListenerThreaded"=>false, "StagerRetryCount"=>10, "StagerRetryWait"=>5, "CreateSession"=>true, "InitialAutoRunScript"=>nil, "AutoRunScript"=>nil, "CommandShellCleanupCommand"=>nil, "AutoVerifySession"=>true, "TARGET"=>0}]>
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

How am i supposed to fix it for my exploit to be successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like according to https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Arapid7/metasploit-framework%20smtp_send_recv&type=code that the function that is missing here is defined in
`lib/msf/core/exploit/remote/smtp_deliver.rb` aka the Msf::Exploit::Remote::SMTPDeliver mixin as noted at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/a526604bb3f36b15a82e385e2e681503c215349c/lib/msf/core/exploit/remote/smtp_deliver.rb#L236.

The file in question is loading from `include Msf::Exploit::Remote::Smtp` however looking at where this file is defined, which is at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/a526604bb3f36b15a82e385e2e681503c215349c/lib/msf/core/exploit/remote/smtp.rb, shows that this file does not import the `Msf::Exploit::Remote::SMTPDeliver` mixin.

My guess is that this is an error on our side and you might be able to patch this temporarily by adding an `include Exploit::Remote::SMTPDeliver` line to the top of your file to include the missing `smtp_send_recv` definition.

Feel free to raise a bug report at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md though as this will help us track and resolve this issue quicker.

Comment: Sory if i understand wrong but include is not a command

Comment: `include` is a Ruby statement that is part of the Ruby programing language. You can find more info on it at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby.

Sorry if that was confusing. I use code formatting to highlight stuff that may be harder to read without it, and these parts were related to Ruby code.

Comment: thank i undertand now